# Python os.walk and symlinks

Tags: python, symlink

While fixing one user's [answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/754931/295286)  , I've discovered a small issue. The code itself is straightforward : os.walk , recursively get sum of all files in the directory.

But it breaks on symlinks :

```
$ python test_code2.py $HOME                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_code2.py", line 8, in <module>
    space += os.stat(os.path.join(subdir, f)).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/xieerqi/.kde/socket-eagle'
```

Question then is, how do I tell python to ignore those files and avoid summing them ?

**Solution**:

As suggested in the comments , I've added `os.path.isfile()` check and now it works perfectly and gives correct size for my home directory

```
$> cat test_code2.py                                                          
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

space = 0L  # L means "long" - not necessary in Python 3
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for f in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, f)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
           space += os.stat(file_path).st_size

sys.stdout.write("Total: {:d}\n".format(space))
$> python test_code2.py  $HOME                                                
Total: 76763501905
```

Comment: it does not break on symlinks. it breaks on *broken* symlinks. In any case you can test with [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) that the filename points to an actual file, before summing its size.

Comment: AHA, sharp, that's why the code works in my test :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so what should the solution be ? Delete the broken symlinks ? Is there a way to get around that in the code itself ?

Comment: Just test if the file exists and skip if not.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala post the answer :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yup, exactly as AntiiHaapala suggested. Added that bit and it works.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  post an answer on how that can be done

Comment: Ah, I see you already edited it in.

Comment: UPV for going extra mile of solving AU problem by posting in SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned by Antti Haapala in a comment, The script does not break on symlinks, but on *broken symlinks*. One way to avoid that, taking the existing script as a starting point, is using `try/except`:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python2
import os
import sys

space = 0L  # L means "long" - not necessary in Python 3
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for f in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        try:
            space += os.stat(fpath).st_size
        except OSError:
            print("could not read "+fpath)

sys.stdout.write("Total: {:d}\n".format(space))
```

As a side effect, it gives you information on possible broken links.

Comment: UPV but didn't you tell me in AU that you never use Python 2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `os.path.isfile` is the way to go. However the following version *may be* more memory efficient.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    paths = (os.path.join(subdir, f) for f in files)
    space = sum(os.stat(path).st_size for path in paths if os.path.isfile(path))
```

Comment: Interesting, why exactly sum() is more memory efficient ?

Comment: @Serg It's not `sum`, it is the use of iterators that result in space efficiency. You can see that `paths` is a genexp. So this declarative style ensures that you are dealing with **one** object at a time while essentially talking about **all** at the same time. There are no intermediate container data structures. But in this example I used "*may be*", as you can see, because there aren't intermediate lists anyway. But has a side effect, `space` is changing.

Comment: This code is certainly more compact but I don't understand how it saves on memory. Perhaps as I learn more Python I'll understand your reply to @SergiyKolodyazhnyy better.